# Accessing a Property

Tags: c#

I have created the below object:

```
public class GameProperties : ModelBase
{
    private int _gameSpeed;
    public virtual int GameSpeed
    {
        get { return _gameSpeed; }
        set
        {
            _gameSpeed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GameSpeed");
        }
    }

    public void SetGameSpeed(int speed)
    {
        _gameSpeed = speed;
    }   

}
```

I set the GameSpeed property when loading my application:

GameProperties newProperty = new GameProperties();
            newProperty.SetGameSpeed(4);

what i want to do is now reference the GameSpeed within another class. Can you please help with this as I am a new developer and can't figure it out.

thank you

Comment: SideNote: in c# you don't need to write Getter and Setters methods.
The SetGameSpeed method is completely useless because you can write the same code into the Set block of the gamespeed property.

Comment: @vaitrafra in the above example they don't do the same and you can't have two setters for the same property (as Im sure you know) :)

Comment: Another sidenote: OnPropertyChanged("GameSpeed"); I don't like that you hardcode the name of the property as string here. You can use lamdas instead to identify the propery instead which allows easier refactoring.

Comment: @Rune FS: for what is my knowledge of the System namespace, that Set block is marshalling the change of the property to some method, probably rising an event.
This behavor is broken by the setter that he has written; in fact, setting the private field directly prevents the OnChange pattern to be called.
So, no need for the setter anyway, IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the `GameProperties` reference to the other class either in the constructor or the method you are calling. For example:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void Foo(GameProperties properties)
    {
        int speed = properties.GameSpeed;
    }
}
```

or in the constructor:

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private readonly GameProperties _properties;
    public SomeOtherClass(GameProperties properties)
    {
        _properties = properties;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        int speed = _properties.GameSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the right answer to your question you should set it as such clicking on the white check on the left of the answer.